# Distributed Locking for Device

Tags: locking, distributed-computing, hazelcast, jgroups, apache-zookeeper

We have distributed cluster weblogic setup.

Our Use Case was whenever Device Contact our system need to compute Parameter and provision to the device. There can be concurrent request from devices. We cant reject any request from devices.So we are going with Async Processing approach.

Here problem we are facing is whenever device contacts we need to lock the source device as well as neighbor devices to provision optimized parameter.
Since we have cluster system, we require a distributed locking system which provides high performance.

Could you suggest us any framework/suggestion in java for distributed locking which suits to our requirement ?

Regards,
Sakumar

Answer (score 4):

Typically, when you sense a need for distributed locking, that indicates a design flaw. Distributed locking is usually either slow or unsafe. It's slow when done correctly because strong consistency guarantees are required to ensure two processes can't hold the same lock at the same time, and unsafe when consistency constraints are relaxed in favor of performance gains.

Often you can find a better solution than distributed locking by doing something like consistent hashing to ensure related requests are handled by the same process. Similarly, leader election can be a more performant alternative to distributed locking if you can elect a leader and route related requests to the leader. But certainly there must be some cases where these solutions are not possible, and so I'd better answer your question...

Assuming fault tolerance is a requirement, and considering the performance and safety concerns mentioned above, [Hazelcast](http://hazelcast.org) may be a good option for your use case. It's a fast embedded in-memory data grid that has a distributed `Lock` implementation. Often it's nice to use an embedded system like Hazelcast rather than relying on another cluster, but Hazelcat does have the potential for consistency issues in certain partition scenarios, and that could result in two processes acquiring a lock. TBH I've heard more than a few complaints about locks in Hazelcast, but no doubt others have had positive experiences.

Alternatively, [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org) is likely the most common system for distributed locking in Java. However, ZooKeeper tends to be significantly slower for writes than reads since its quorum based - though it is relatively fast and very mature - and locking is a write-heavy work load. Also, in contrast to Hazelcast, one major downside to ZooKeeper is that it's a separate cluster and thus a dependency on another external system. I think ZooKeeper's stability and maturity makes it worth a look.

There doesn't currently seem to be many proven projects in between Hazelcast (an embedded eventually strongly consistent framework) and ZooKeeper (a strongly consistent external service) which is why (disclaimer: self promotion incoming) I created [Atomix](http://github.com/atomix/atomix) to provide safe distributed locking and leader elections as an embedded system for Java. It's a decent option if you need a framework like Hazelcast that has the same (actually stronger) consistency guarantees as ZooKeeper.

If performance and scalability is paramount and you're expecting high rates of requests, you will likely have to sacrifice consistency and look at a Hazelcast or something similar.

Alternatively, if fault tolerance is not a requirement (I don't think you spshould cities that it is) you can even just use a [Redis](http://redis.io) instance :-)

Comment: Could you please expand on "the consistency issues in partition scenarios in Hazelcast" described in the post ?

Comment: Thanks Kuujo , This is definitely not a design flaw , we can't deny any request from device at the same time we can't end up in inconsistent in computation Do you know any framework which provides async lock feature I mean it should give call back once lock success